# Custom Error Pages in Old ASP.Net Applications Not Working

Tags: asp.net, webforms

I have a couple older ASP.Net WebForms apps that I recently altered to support custom error pages. The error pages work just find for 404 errors unless the 404 status code is generated programmatically using code behind.

In this specific case I have configured my WebForms to return 404 errors if a hidden field loads. The hidden field loads whenever someone tried to access the form and the DetailsView does not have a relevant record to display. When that happens I had been redirecting users via 301 to a different page. I chose a 301 instead of a 404 because back in the day there was evidence indicating that search engines would still credit your site with backlinks to pages that returned 301 status codes, but if they returned 404 status codes the link would not be counted, so it was best to return a "moved permanently" status rather than a "not found" status for as many missing items as possible. In the years since it seems Google has started recognizing what they call a "soft 404" which includes pages being redirected to completely different pages. Now I think a 404 would be better, plus sites that feed off them want a way to let users remove outdated content if the source URL is dead.

The problem I have now is that although a 404 error is returned, the custom error page is not loaded. I don't even get the standard IIS error page. I just get an error in my browser that says
"This example.com page can’t be found No webpage was found for the web address: https://example.com/missingpage.aspx HTTP ERROR 404" but if I try to load a non-existent physical file the custom error page is displayed properly.

My web.config has the following lines of code

```
<customErrors mode="RemoteOnly" defaultRedirect="~/error/">
      <error statusCode="404" redirect="~/error/"/>
      <error statusCode="500" redirect="~/error/"/>
    </customErrors>
<system.webServer>
<httpErrors errorMode="Custom">
      <remove statusCode="404" />
      <error statusCode="404" path="/error/" responseMode="ExecuteURL" />
      <remove statusCode="500" />
      <error statusCode="500" path="/error/" responseMode="ExecuteURL" />
    </httpErrors>
</system.webServer>
```

Then in my .aspx page I have this:

```
protected void HiddenField1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Response.Clear();
        Response.Status = "404 Not Found";
        Response.StatusCode = 404;
        Response.End();
    }
```

The only difference between these sites and another site which used a similar approach to achieve the desired results are that the other site was originally designed using ASP.Net 4+ while the others were designed using ASP.Net 2.0 but were later upgraded to more recent versions of the framework, and the other site added the redirect to the page load event after checking the ObjectDataSource for matching active posts.

UPDATE: Today I realized that the error appears lined to Response.End, but if I get rid of Response.End I get an error that a label in the DetailsView cannot be found. That would make sense in a situation in which the hidden field in the empty data template loads.

Answer (score 0):

In my `web.config file` I have something like this.

```
<customErrors defaultRedirect="/ErrorFiles/Internal_Server_Error.html" mode="Off">
  <error statusCode="403" redirect="/ErrorFiles/NoAccess.html" />
  <error statusCode="404" redirect="/ErrorFiles/Not_Found.html" />
  <error statusCode="503" redirect="/ErrorFiles/Maintenance.html" />
</customErrors>
```

Comment: The problem seems linked to Response.End